# getopts bash query for argument check

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a getops script as below..
I am facing an issue with this script..
The usage is

```
Usage: ./getoptstest.sh [-f] [ -i INSTANCES ]
```

If I pass,./getoptstest.sh -f -i 1.2.3.4 ,it works fine with the result,

```
Result
    f good
    i good
    1.2.3.4
    No args
```

But if I switch the options,./getoptstest.sh -i -f ,its taking "-f" as the argument for "-i".

```
Result:
    i good
    -f -->This is the result of echo statement printing the argument for -i.
    No args
```

I want the script to strictly check -i argument and not take -f as its argument.-f is a different option by itself.
Please help me what to modify to achieve this.

Here is my script..

```
while getopts ":hfi:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        i)  INSTANCES="$OPTARG"
            echo "i good"
            echo $INSTANCES
            ;;
        f)  FORCE=1
            echo "f good"
            ;;
        h)  usage
            exit;;
        \?) echo "Usage: Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            ;;
        :)  echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
        *)  usage 
            exit;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: What determines if an argument is valid as the argument to `-`i: does it have to be a dotted-quad IP address, or just not start with a `-`?

Comment: i is EC2 instance names..For testing purpose,i have kept i as any value.But i dont want to see the next option -f as value to -i

Comment: Is `-f` an invalid EC2 instance name?

Comment: yes...Basically i want to check -i <with argument> -f. When I dont pass any value to -i,-f itself is taken as argument to -i instead of throwing error like "-i needs atleast 1 argument"

Comment: `-f` *is* an argument. I asked if `-f` was a valid instance name because unless you can perform some test on the value of `INSTANCES` that shows it cannot possibly be a valid name, there's nothing you can do. `-f` doesn't become an invalid argument simply because there is also an option named `-f`.

Comment: Ok..Thankyou ..let me check then